# How do i create an instance of UserManager

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am trying to learn how the new asp.net identity 2.0 works, but with little documentation I am hitting quite a few stumbling blocks.

I have this code below based off of a couple of tutorials that I have read:

```
public class CustomRole : IdentityRole<string, CustomUserRole>
{
    public CustomRole() { }
    public CustomRole(string name) { Name = name; }
}

public class CustomUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string> { }
public class CustomUserClaim : IdentityUserClaim<string> { }
public class CustomUserLogin : IdentityUserLogin<string> { }

// define the application user
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser<string, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, 
    CustomUserClaim>
{
    [Required]
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }

    public async Task<ClaimsIdentity> GenerateUserIdentityAsync(UserManager<ApplicationUser> manager)
    {
        // Note the authenticationType must match the one defined in CookieAuthenticationOptions.AuthenticationType
        var userIdentity = await manager.CreateIdentityAsync(this, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        // Add custom user claims here
        return userIdentity;


    }
}

public partial class myDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, string, 
    CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
{
    static myDbContext()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer<myDbContext>(null);
    }

    public myDbContext()
        : base("Name=myDbContext")
    {
    }

    public DbSet<TestTable> TestTables { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Configurations.Add(new TestTableMap());
    }
}
```

I then have this code:

```
// create the user manager
        UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, string, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,
    CustomUserClaim>(
            new myDbContext()));
```

I get an error in this statement saying the argument type **UserStore<-ApplicationUser, CustomRole, string, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole,
        CustomUserClaim->** is not assignable to the parameter type **IUserStore<-ApplicationUser->**

What am I missing here?

Comment: Is there a reason why you're introducing your custom role/claim/login classes, with no additional functionality?

Comment: this needs to be done if you implementing custom user with non-default   key type... in his case it's a `string` (although it's a default value). I, for example, wanted to use `int` and did the same thing. Although there might be other cases why you'd want to do that

Answer (score 10, accepted):

try this:

```
UserManager = new UserManager<ApplicationUser,string>(new UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, string, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>(new myDbContext()));
```

note I use a different construction for `UserManager`, I added `string` as a second type that you use in your code for ApplicationUser primary key

Since you implemented custom user/roles/etc the way you did, you'll need to use `UserManager` as `UserManager<ApplicationUser,string>` throughout your code to pass in the type for User PK as a string.

Answer (score 3):

This worked me. Seems you have to create own usermanager and userstore if you create custom users and roles. This is the derived UM(you can create the same way the rolemanager too):

```cs
public class ApplicationUserManager : UserManager<ApplicationUser, string>
    {
        public ApplicationUserManager(IUserStore<ApplicationUser, string> store)
            : base(store)
        {

        }


    }
public class ApplicationUserStore : UserStore<ApplicationUser, CustomRole, string, CustomUserLogin, CustomUserRole, CustomUserClaim>
    {
        public ApplicationUserStore(ApplicationDbContext context)
            : base(context)
        {
        }
    }
```

Then create the UserManager:

```cs
ApplicationUserManager um = new ApplicationUserManager(new ApplicationUserStore(new ApplicationDbContext()));
```