# Getting Null Exception at UserManager.GetRoles(Convert.ToInt32(userid))

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Exception:  Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

```
  {System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
at System.Web.HttpContextExtensions.GetOwinEnvironment(HttpContext context)
at System.Web.HttpContextExtensions.GetOwinContext(HttpContext context)
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not instantiate `UserManager`, but trying to use it as a `static` class which it is not.

Use the `new` keyword ([how do I create an instance of `UserManager`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924816/how-do-i-create-an-instance-of-usermanager)).