# Remove a user from a role

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, model-view-controller

I'm making a small easy web application project to learn better and using asp.net core 6.0 mvc with identity and I have two roles, admin and user. I want to give the admin the possibility to block a user. For that I know that I have to create a third role  but since I'm still a beginner, I don't know exactly what to do next. I found a lot of tutorials like this https://csharp-video-tutorials.blogspot.com/2019/07/add-or-remove-users-from-role-in-aspnet.html but they all have in common something that I can't access, the userManager. Example

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> EditUsersInRole(string roleId)
{
    ViewBag.roleId = roleId;

    var role = await roleManager.FindByIdAsync(roleId);

    if (role == null)
    {
        ViewBag.ErrorMessage = $"Role with Id = {roleId} cannot be found";
        return View("NotFound");
    }

    var model = new List<UserRoleViewModel>();

    foreach (var user in userManager.Users)
    {
        var userRoleViewModel = new UserRoleViewModel
        {
            UserId = user.Id,
            UserName = user.UserName
        };

        if (await userManager.IsInRoleAsync(user, role.Name))
        {
            userRoleViewModel.IsSelected = true;
        }
        else
        {
            userRoleViewModel.IsSelected = false;
        }

        model.Add(userRoleViewModel);
    }

    return View(model);
}
```

userManager.Users gives an error "The name 'userManager' does not exist in the current context"
Also roleManager.FindByIdAsync gives the same error

I'm using an ApplicationUser class

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public virtual Profile? Profile { get; set; }
    }
```

The ApplicationDbContext is

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
    {
        public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options)
            : base(options)
        {
        }

        public ApplicationDbContext() {}

        public DbSet<Profile> Profiles { get; set; }


        protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
        {
            string connection = @"Server=(localdb)\mssqllocaldb;Database=ExerciseDb; Trusted_Connection=True;";
            optionsBuilder.UseLazyLoadingProxies().UseSqlServer(connection);
        }

        protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
        {
            base.OnModelCreating(builder);
            builder.HasDefaultSchema("Identity");
            builder.Entity<IdentityUser>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "User");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable(name: "Role");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserRole<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserRoles");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserClaims");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserLogins");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityRoleClaim<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("RoleClaims");
            });
            builder.Entity<IdentityUserToken<string>>(entity =>
            {
                entity.ToTable("UserTokens");
            });

            builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
                .HasOne(a => a.Profile)
                .WithOne(p => p.ApplicationUser)
                .HasForeignKey<Profile>(p => p.ApplicationUserId);

            builder.Entity<IdentityRole>().HasData(
                new IdentityRole() { Id = "1", Name = "Admin" },
                new IdentityRole() { Id = "2", Name = "Client" }
                new IdentityRole() { Id = "3", Name = "Authorized" }
            );
```

Comment: If you do not want use Identity, why you use IdentityDbContext? What if using Cookie authentication or jwt authentication? I think you need share your scenario.

Answer (score 0):

You have not define the variables `userManager` and `roleManager`. You are referring to things that have not yet been defined.

See the follow previous stack overflow question on how to define and initalise an instance of `UserManager`: [How do i create an instance of UserManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22924816/how-do-i-create-an-instance-of-usermanager)

Comment: Thank you. I'm trying to figure out how to do that, even with the link you shared, since I'm still a beginner, I don't know what goes where. Is there any way of doing this without the identity? I have a view for the admin role and I want to add in that view the possibility of that role to restrict some users from accessing the web app, like a ban or a suspended account. I'm using the ApplicationUser to try to avoid dealing with the identity since that's still very confusing for me to understand.